Want to set the Pre-loader only for the HOME page using PHP
<!-- preloader -->
    <div class="art-preloader">
      <!-- preloader content -->
      <div class="art-preloader-content">
        <!-- title -->
        <h5>Loading the &nbsp <span style="color: #FFC107;">page</span> </h5>
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <div id="preloader" class="art-preloader-load"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- preloader content end -->
    </div>
    <!-- preloader end -->

I am basically using a web template made of **Bootstrap **and for my **Backend **I am using row PHP. And this is my pre-loader HTML code. Now as I have multiple pages like "Home, About, Contact, etc". Every time I refresh any page it shows the pre-loader. But I want to show the pre-loader when only my home page is loaded. If anyone could help me to solve the problem using inner PHP code ??
I am beginner, I dont have that much idea on PHP but am trying to learn it as much as I can. Talking about the specific problem, I tried to use inner PHP code like using IF/ELSE statement to solve the problem but it didn't work.

Didn't work in what way exactly? Show us what you tried in case we can easily fix it. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your question. Thanks

First of all, please don't just vaguely talk about what you tried - but show it, and explain your reasoning behind it. Second - we currently have little idea, how your system works, whether your pages are individual script files, whether you are using some sort of router, etc. So your question is basically not really answerable for us at this point. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.
